# How can I replace 'system' libraries on IBM Analytics Engine?

Tags: ibm-cloud, analytics-engine

To help debug an issue with a yarn application, I need to modify some of the system code on IAE to provide more debug output.

I have retrieved this jar file from the cluster to my local machine:

```
/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/hadoop-aws.jar
```

I've modified the bytecode to log more information when the an exception is thrown on `checkOpen()`:

```
public class S3AOutputStream extends OutputStream {
  ...
  void checkOpen() throws IOException {
    if (closed.get()) {

      // some log4j statements added to the bytecode here ...

      throw new IOException("Output Stream closed");
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

However, I'm unable to save the library with my changes back to the cluster because I don't have root access.

How can I deploy my modified jar files to the cluster?  Assume that I need to install the libraries on the name node and compute nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible with IBM Analytics Engine.

Please raise a support ticket describing your issue.

Comment: If it is an enhancement request, it is better to open a request here rather than open a ticket: https://ibmcloud.ideas.aha.io/